# Playground wrong output

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I wonder if this is playground bug or it's supposed to work like this:

```
var types = ["0", "1", "2"]      // ["0","1","2"]
    types += "3"                 // ["0","1","2","3"]
    types += ["4", "5"]          // ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
    types[3..5] = ["34"]         // ["34"]
```

In my opinion in last line `types` should contain `["0","1","2","34","5"]`, however playground gives different output - written on the right.

I would consider that on the right we can see only last edited stuff, but in line 2&3 we can see whole types array.

In assistant editor I get `[0] "34"`, while it should be `[3] "34"` and rest of array in my opinion.

Comment: I guess it shows the result for LHS. In your last line it would be `types[3..5]` which is (after assignment) `["34"]`. It is also consistent with `[0] "34"` you get with assistant editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing only `["34"]` after the `types[3..<5] = ["34"]` line is because the assignment operator `=` returns the value that has been assigned.

The other lines show the whole array because the `+=` operator returns the result of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

`var` refers to the **mutable content** and also you'r re assigning the values to it .

`types[]` - new value at index , mean it shouldn't be concatenate .

For Ex :

```
var types = ["0", "1", "2"]
types += "5"
types += ["4", "5"]
types[3..5] = ["34"] // Here considering the index of 3..5 (3 & 4) as one index - Assigning a single value  and replaced with the value
types
```

[image]